# Git Plugin for Jenkins on MacOS Slave doesn't checkout as expected

Tags: macos, jenkins

I'm having a small but significant problem with Jenkins.
I've setup the Jenkins CI on a Windows 7 machine, and also a slave through Java WebStart, on a Mac Mini.
I've had some issue setting up ssh connection to the git repo, but I've figured it out.
Now I'm having troubles running the build on my Mac Mini.
Basically, the job seems to clone the repo ok, but when the build script runs, it finds some folders as files:

```
cc1objplus: error: 3rdParty/sparkle/Sparkle.framework/Headers: not a directory
```

I've checked with git command, and it is so.

EDIT: I've checked the files from the repo and they are files instead of directories.
It seems that somehow Git Plugin is outputting files instead of directories.

I've cloned, checked out, pulled, fetched, whatever, using git command, and everything is ok.
I've run bash commands instead of using Git Plugin (like "git clone", "git checkout", etc), and the job runs fine when I do that.
It fails when the repo is checked out using Git Plugin.

This project builds fine on Windows 7. And if I do it from bash, it builds also on Mac.

UPDATE: `git status` shows this:

```
#    typechange: 3rdParty/sparkle/Sparkle.framework/Headers
```

for each of the files that were supposed to be folders.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case here, but it sure looks like there's a space in the path someplace that isn't quoted.   Most of the build tools on the Mac use full paths, so I'd expect to see a path in cc1objplus beginning with `/`.   Not finding the directory would also result in the "not a directory" error (if the directory doesn't exist, it's not a directory), and building a different way might have different quoting.   Check your logs to see if this might be the case.

Comment: Hi gaige, as I said, I've checked and they actually are files instead of directories. I've switched to pulling changes from bash instead of using the Git Plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry "I checked with git command" didn't make it clear that you'd verified that they were not files on the file system. To me, it sounded like you had verified that git had what you expected (which was presumedly a directory).  Perhaps you can clarify this in your original piece.